# XCODE trying to search and replace in localy loaded html

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, replace

I admit I am no Javascript expert, and this one is really giving me trouble any help is greatly appreciated

this is what I got so far
inside html there is javascript

```
<head>
<script type='text/javascript'>
function findAndReplace(searchText, replacement) 
{

    alert('pokrecemo find and replace');

        if (!searchText || typeof replacement === 'undefined') {
        // Throw error here if you want...
        alert('govno greska u parametrima')
        return;## Heading ##
    }
    var regex = typeof searchText === 'string' ?
                new RegExp(searchText, 'g') : searchText,
        childNodes = document.body.childNodes,
        cnLength = childNodes.length,
        excludes = 'head,style,meta,script';
    while (cnLength--) {
        var currentNode = childNodes[cnLength];
        if (currentNode.nodeType === 1 &&
            (excludes + ',').indexOf(currentNode.nodeName.toLowerCase() + ',') === -1) {
            arguments.callee(searchText, replacement, currentNode);
        }
        if (currentNode.nodeType !== 3 || !regex.test(currentNode.data) ) {
            continue;
        }
        var parent = currentNode.parentNode,
            frag = (function(){
                var html = currentNode.data.replace(regex, replacement),
                    wrap = document.createElement('div'),
                    frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
                wrap.innerHTML = html;
                while (wrap.firstChild) {
                    frag.appendChild(wrap.firstChild);
                }
                return frag;
            })();
        parent.insertBefore(frag, currentNode);
        parent.removeChild(currentNode);
    }
}


</script>
....
</head>
```

### and XCODE

```
(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {  
    if (index.row==7) {  
    script=@"findAndReplace(75,900)";  



NSLog(@"%@",script);  
[self.tekst stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:script];  

}
```

}

and in viewdidload
.....
        case 7:
                `[tekst loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL`  `

```
fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sometest" ofType:@"html
"]`isDirectory:NO]]];  




tekst.delegate = self; 



break;
```

.....

what I am doing wrong
I can see that javascript is starting but it does exactly nothing!!!

Comment: Please don't ask the same question multiple times. Be patient or improve your question to get a "bump". Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Are you just trying to do a find and replace? This would be much easier to accomplish in Objective-C.

```
NSString *htmlString =  [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:@"pathToFile" encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

NSString *finalString = [htmlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"75" withString:@"900"];
```

Then to load the new string

```
[webView loadHTMLString:finalString baseURL:someURLHere];
```

Comment: Ah okay, just edited my answer to include editing the HTML string then loading the final string in a webView.

Comment: got it, replaced  someURLHere with nil and it works like charm  Brandon you are a genius

Comment: one thing though it totally destroys html struncture like collapsible panels, so it is only good in limited things, I am afraid I am back to square one

Comment: if I load html into string it destroys collapsible panels, I will have to go back to javascript, ahh what frustration

Comment: Then instead write the string back to an HTML file.

Comment: could be done but this turns to more work than calling javascript

Comment: if I understand I have to write to documents folder which is another question for itself!!!

Comment: wrote it to file, read it from new html file still the same, other javascript functions gone, not working, great idea but not working

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need the semicolon after the JavaScript.

```
script=@"findAndReplace(75,900);";
```

Comment: doesn't change a thing unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

there was a mistake in javascript, I placed it in dreamweaver and it immediatly recognized syntax error, by removing this error everything works fine, and there should be no semicolon as suggested by picciano, it starts to behave well at least oddly, don't know why, there should be semicolon but it only works correctly without it

by removing this

```
   if (!searchText || typeof replacement === 'undefined') {
    // Throw error here if you want...
    alert('govno greska u parametrima')
    return;## Heading ##
}
```

everything works fine

original coding is here
http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/find-and-replace-text-with-javascript/